# Where to find relation of custom post type category with it thubmnail image in wordpress database

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Actually i have installed a theme and that has custom post type with categories. I have created categories and searched in database that are being inserted into terms and taxonomy tables. And thumbnail is inserted into posts postmeta tables. but i failed to find any relation between category and thumbnail.

What i have understood wordpress db structure. The image is on url.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14v0SSzufl1OJ1kylTW1WBv6YClCXINBz/view?usp=sharing

The post **3230** is just for understanding, there is no post no **3230**.
Can someone explain me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no relationship between categories and thumbnails. Thumbnails belong to posts.

Comment: i have added thumbnail to the category. then how to fetch that thumbnail

Comment: can you tell me what is tax_meta

Comment: How did you add the thumbnail to the category taxonomy? Did you use a plugin like ACF or CMB2? Those plugins should have documentation that shows you how to look up post-meta from taxonomies.

Comment: No that comes with the theme, there is no plugin

Comment: @HabibUrRehman Then consult the theme documentation. Nobody here can tell you how the theme does this with the information given.

Comment: Actually i got the same problem couple of days ago, same theme, same project, but it solved by  **get_tax_meta( $air_line['term_id'], 'air_line_image', true )**.

Comment: can you tell me **get_tax_meta** is wordpress function or not

Comment: It’s not. Unless you mean get_term_meta(). If you _do_ mean get_tax_meta(), then that’s something custom from your theme.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: you could update your question sharing how did you found the proper function on your theme and the answer sharing the solution